# How to return a django queryset in ajax httpresponse

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I've been trying to retrieve a Django queryset and store it in a Javascript variable through Ajax.

I'm currently trying to use the code below but I keep on receiving the "Queryset is not JSON Serializable. I'm quite new to both django and json formats. How do I workaround this?

html/javascript page

```
$.ajax({url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/getPorts,
    success: function(result){
        var res = JSON.parse(result);
    }
});
```

views.py

```
def getPorts(request):
    JSONer = {} 
    ports = Port.objects.all()

    JSONer['ports'] = ports

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(JSONer))
```

Also, if anyone would like to suggest a better way to use ajax to send/retrieve data to/from views, I am open to advice. Thank you

Comment: Try `JSONer['ports'] = list(ports.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try serializing the queryset before sending it back to the ajax like this:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('json', list(ports))
```

You can specify the required fields as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in `JsonResponse`, that way you don't have to call `json.dumps()` and it will also set the proper headers.

First your JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/getPorts',
  dataType: 'json',
  sucess: function (result) {
    console.log(result.ports);
  }
});
```

By setting the `dataType` you already get a parsed object. Also, you don't need to hardcore the absolute url in the `url` parameter.

Then, in your view:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def getPorts(request):
    JSONer = {} 
    ports = Port.objects.values()
    JSONer['ports'] = ports
    return JsonResponse(JSONer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You don't

Please understand, `querysets` are not actual serializable data. They just help in querying that data from the database.

And as others have pointed, just convert them to a json response either by using `JsonResponse` or manually dumping into as `json` and sending it in the `HttpResponse`.